# Mongodb $count in aggregation is too slow, working with more than 1mill. docs in db

Tags: mongodb, optimization, count, bigdata, aggregate

I'm trying to filter array of embedded documents and get count sum in all documents.

Data structure in database.

```
{
     name: String,
     transactions: [{
      type: String,
      isValid: String
     }]
}
```

I am also using multiple indexex for type & isValid fields.

This is my aggregation.

```
 await Collection.aggregate([
  { '$unwind': '$transactions' },
  { '$replaceRoot': { newRoot: '$transactions' } },
  { '$match': { '$and': [ { type: { '$eq': 'Anything' } },
  { '$or': [ { isValid: { '$eq': true } }, { isValid: { '$eq': null } } ] } ] } },
  { '$count': "count"}]
```

Delay is ~15sec.

```
 await Collection.aggregate([
  { '$count': "count"}]
```

Using only $count in aggregation delay is the same ~15sec. Can't figure out how it works.

Collection doc. count is more than 1mill. and getting count sum for embedded array took ~15sec.
Anybody can advice how to optimize the query?

Comment: Please Post a sample document from your collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Implementing this:

```
 await Collection.aggregate([
  {$group:{_id:null,count:{$sum:{$size:
                                {
                                    $filter: {
                                        input: "$transactions", as: "item",
                                        cond:
                                            {$and: [
                                                {$eq: ["$$item.type", "Anything"]},
            { '$or': [ { "$eq":["$$item.isValid",true]},{ "$eq":["$$item.isValid",null]}] }
                                            ]}
                                    }
                                }}}}}])
```

Comment: I have an error. with this message: "The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: null"

Comment: For $size need an array to run you can add cond in $size with
{$cond:{if:{$lte:["$transactions",null]},then:[],else:{$size: {
                                    $filter: {
                                        input: "$transactions", as: "item",
                                        cond:
                                            {$and: [
                                                {$eq: ["$$item.type", "Anything"]},
            { '$or': [ { "$eq":["$$item.isValid",true]},{ "$eq":["$$item.isValid",null]}] }]}}}}}